# Centering icons in mini horizontal grouped buttons jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using jQuery mobile and i created a mini horizontal groupe of buttons, the problem is that the icon inside those buttons aren't in the center. 
Any help please to fix this problem ?

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="plus" data-theme="b">Add</a>
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="delete" data-theme="b">Delete</a>
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="grid" data-theme="b">More</a>
```

Comment: you can throw in a class for <a>s and then position those accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try adding `data-iconpos="center"` to the parent div element and you should also close out the `div` tag, unless you purposely didn't add the closing `</div>` tag.

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true" data-iconpos="center">
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="plus" data-theme="b">Add</a>
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="delete" data-theme="b">Delete</a>
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="grid" data-theme="b">More</a>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rNvEc/)